# how to search encrypted data in grails

Tags: java, grails, encryption, grails-searchable

I have domain with 3 field cardNo, cardName and account

```
class card {
    String cardNo
    String cardName
    Account account

static constraints = {
    cardNo(blank:false, unique:true)
    cardName(blank:false)
    account(blank:false)
}
```

The cardNo must be encrypted when saved, I used encryptionUtil Java to encrypt it.
On my list screen, I want to make search fiture, which can be search by cardNo and cardName.
Is it possibe if I search data encrypted with create cretiria in grails??
If can't use create criteria, what is the best way to search encrypted data??
Need your help. thanks before :)

Comment: Unless you're going to reproduce the exact same encrypted value as a search parameter, you cannot search into encrypted data. That's one of the points of the encryption.

Answer (score 3):

I can give you an advice: avoid store card numbers in your database. Use payment services for it.

Comment: Hmm I store the cardNo in database by encrypted it, then in my list I want to search by cardNo for exampe the cardNo is 112211, then in the search textfield I input "1" then klik the search button, and then on the list table the cardName and account with that cardNo 112211 will be appeared.